# When will Solana Delegation Program signups resume?

Tags: testnet, delegation

I'm all ready to join the Solana delegation program, but the signup page has been/is showing that signups are disabled due to maintenance.  Any ideas on when it will reopen?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this site is for developer Q&A, not questions of programs from specific companies